# Metrics empty data with Spring Boot and Actuator #28266

Tags: spring

I have issue in Spring boot with Actuator.
The metrics not display data, like with attachment image

metrics issue empty data [1]

I use JDK 8 with Spring boot version 2.5.5, and I don't use Spring data or JPA, just Spring boot + Actuator + Web only.

And I try it with scratch Spring project with same Spring version boot 2.5.5 and I also get this issue.

Please any help
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKtfA.png

Answer (score 2):

I was misunderstand the Metrics.

This link:
http://localhost:8080/actuator/metrics

its just display keys of metrics, not info of them.
We need to take the key and put it in the other URL, like below:

http://localhost:8080/actuator/metrics/http.server.requests